# Rails url_for cannot match route to it's own recognize_path hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Basically trying to use a parameter :id to access some constant stuff. I.e., `/:thingy_found_in_database/generic_route/:id` where `:id` is a known constant. I.e.,

```
scope ':entity_id', constraints: { entity_id: Slug::VALID_REGEX } do
      resources :slide, controller: :slide, only: [:show], as: :slide
end
```

This cannot find the URL

```
  url_for {:controller=>"slide", :action=>"show", :id=>:story, 
:only_path=>true, :entity_id=>"a0692b03-2d1280860e3f"}
```

Edit:

This is the info using rails routes -g slide --expanded

```
--[ Route 1 ]-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Prefix            | slide
Verb              | GET
URI               | /:entity_id/slide/:id(.:format)
Controller#Action | slide#show {:entity_id=>/[\d\w.+-]+/}
```

Comment: What is the output of `rails routes` in a shell program?

Comment: @Chiperific I added additional info to the original post in an edit section at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

I have just tested with

```
url_for(:controller=>"slide", :action=>"show", :id=>:story, :only_path=>true, :entity_id=>"a0692b03-2d1280860e3f")
```

The `URL` will be `"/a0692b03-2d1280860e3f/slide/story"`.

I just notice the syntax is not correct

```
url_for {:controller=>"slide", :action=>"show", :id=>:story, 
:only_path=>true, :entity_id=>"a0692b03-2d1280860e3f"}
```